# MS Access Error MSysCompactError and Corruption Relationships Removed

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

**Background:**

We are experiencing a strange and concerning issue with an MS Access 2007 file (ACCDB) that we created and distributed to a handful of sites.  The tool was used for a data collection effort and the basic underlying data design was a parent table with 3 child tables linked with foreign keys and referential integrity enforced through Access.  There was a single data entry form, which contained embedded sub forms for creating the associated child records for the parent entity.  Aside from some pretty straight forward VBA code to help with informational pop ups and some basic skip logic, its pretty straight forward, nothing too crazy.

The files were distributed to about 5 different sites.  The sites create multiple copies of the original file, for each of the end users to enter their own data into and ultimately send back to us.  We did not instruct them to split the database file, which seems to be a best practice, as we can never be sure if the different users at the sites will be on machines connected to a network or if all users have access to a shared location for the backend file.  Also the people actually using the tools are not typically tech-savy, so keeping the process as straight forward and least burdensome for them is a priority.

**Problem:**

When the files were ultimately returned to us from one of the sites, we encountered a strange issue in which we saw a table called MSysCompactError created and the relationship constraints between the parent table and the three child table were non-existent.  Through Access, going into Database Tools > Relationships, the relationships are no longer there connecting the child tables to the parent table.  3 of the 4 files at this site experienced this issue – and none of the other sites (with a total of 15-20 other tools/Access files) had any issues.
In each of the three files from the site that exhibited the problem, the date time that the MSysCompactError table was created was days apart.

**The MSysCompactError table created had the following records:**

```
ErrorCode: -1206
ErrorDescription: Unrecognized database format {PATH-TO-FILE-ON-SITES-NETWORK}
ErrorTable: {ParentTable}

ErrorCode: -1053
ErrorDescription: Index or primary key cannot contain a Null Value
ErrorTable: {ParentTable}

ErrorCode: -1522
ErrorDescription: No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table. 
ErrorTable: {ChildTable1}

ErrorCode: -1522
ErrorDescription: No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table.
ErrorTable: {ChildTable2}

ErrorCode: -1522
ErrorDescription: No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table.
ErrorTable: {ChildTable3}
```

The error tables name suggests, at least to me, that the Backup and Repair function was run on the files.  The sites did not indicate having any issue/error using the tool.  Luckily this error happened toward the end of the data collection effort, looking at the create date time of the records, only a handful were created after the error table was created.  We did experience some orphaned records in the child tables – as in two of the files there was a single record with “########” appearing for all fields.  Also, it looks like someone deleted a record or two from the parent table after the corruption occurred and the associated cascading deletes that should have happened, did not since the relationships were removed.

I hope no one else has experienced this issue but I’m wondering if anyone has any good theories about why it could have happened.  Given that the issue was confined to one site and the first error in the table referencing the path on their network, we are thinking it has to do with their network/set up. One theory proposed was that perhaps some automated process, maybe a virus scanner or backup utility, accessed the file and caused the issue.  I know that just opening an Access file updates the Last Modified Date Time.  We've done similar data collection efforts, following the same basic procedure/methodology, distributing the files with these types of relational data structures to sites for data entry and have never run into this issue before.

Comment: It sounds like you under Settings, Current database have marked the option: Compact when closing. Remove that mark. The compact can fail if the file is run off a network drive.

Comment: I just confirmed that the "Compact on close" option was not enabled on the file.

Comment: It can also happen if the database is compacted manually, indeed off a network drive. Or that table wouldn't exist. Always make a backup before attempting a compact.

Comment: None of the users indicate that they performed the compacting function - none even know what it was.  Do you believe it is possible that an automated process opening or indexing the file could have somehow caused Compact and Repair to run?  Would Access run it by itself for any reason? I can't seem to understand how an error message "unrecognized database format" would make sense appearing in a table referencing the file itself which is an Access database file.

Comment: Strange - though I have seen something like that at launch; in that case Access just restarts and leave a backup of the file with "_backup" as suffix to the original file name. You could ask the user(s) to look for such a file.